# How should I write SQL triggers to add up to a total of some payments made over a month?

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am just starting to learn how to get used to creating triggers in SQL. So far, the most understandable format to me looks like this:

```
create trigger [trigger_name]
[before | after] 
{insert | update | delete}
on [table_name]
[for each row]
[trigger_body]
```

Now, I need help trying to use this format to track down payments made over one month and calculate the total as if it will garner some monthly profit. So far, the table I want to use looks like this:

```
/* CREATE A TABLE FOR PAYMENT INFORMATION */
CREATE TABLE PAYMENT
(
    PAY_ID NUMERIC(10),
    ORDER_NO NUMERIC(10),
    CARD_TYPE VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    PRICE NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,
    PAY_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    PAY_CONF INTEGER NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_PAYMENT PRIMARY KEY (PAY_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PAYMENT_ORDER_NO 
        FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_NO) REFERENCES PRODUCTS
);
```

Also, I want to keep a record of weekly deliveries where I can calculate the total of deliveries made this week using a table like this:

```
/* CREATE A TABLE FOR PRODUCT DELIVERY INFORMATION */
CREATE TABLE DELIVERY
(
    DEL_ID NUMERIC(10),
    ORDER_NO NUMERIC(10),
    DEL_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    STATUS VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    DEL_MODE VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    INVOICE_NO INTEGER NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_DELIVERY PRIMARY KEY (DEL_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_DELIVERY_ORDER_NO 
        FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_NO) REFERENCES PRODUCTS,
);
```

This is another college assignment I am working on. The lecture notes from that class had some typos that caused some errors for me, so I researched for simpler explanations and demonstrations. I only need to determine if using [the above example from GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-trigger-student-database/) will be good enough for simple monthly or weekly calculations.

Comment: Why use a trigger? Why not use a view to aggregate the data?

Comment: @MT0 because my assignment specifically needed me to create triggers and I figured maybe I should see if triggers can be used to calculate monthly total payments or weekly total deliveries.